# NullPointerException trying to call toString()

Tags: java, exception

I have done this code:

```
Table tb;
Exam[] examArr;
int day, month, year, lengt;
String subject, room;
Date d;
lengt = reader.nextInt();
examArr = new Exam[lengt];
for(int i = 0; i<testArr.length; i++)
{
     System.out.println("Enter day, month, year.");
     day = reader.nextInt();
     month = reader.nextInt();
     year = reader.nextInt();
     d = new Date(day, month, year);
     System.out.println("Enter subject.");
     subject = reader.next();
     examArr[i] = new Exam(subject, d);
}
System.out.println("Enter room.");
room = reader.next();
tb = new Table(room, examArr);
System.out.println(tb.toString());
```

I get an exception that says `NullPointerException at Table.toString(Table.java:43)`. I go to the `Table` class that has:
`private Test[] arr;`
`private String room;`
The `toString()` method is:

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0; i<this.arr.length;i++)
{
     s += arr[i].toString();
}
return s;
```

The program marks the line `s += arr[i].toString();` in yellow.
The `toString()` of `Exam` is

```
return subject + " " + this.testDay.toString();
```

The `toString()` of `Date` is

```
return day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
```

I think I'm giving the needed information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @VGR Nope. I have read those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be in:

```
...

for(int i = 0; i<this.arr.length;i++)
{
     s += arr[i].toString();
}

...
```

as you iterate through this.arr but you use arr[i].toString()
did you by any change mean this.arr[i].toString() ? Also check if your array contains something else than nulls.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
System.out.println(tb.toString());
```

What is `Table` class, you can't use `toString` for that class because the `tb` variable is `null`

Answer (score -2):

Always check if the object is null before calling it's methods

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0; i<this.arr.length;i++)
{
 if(arr[i]!=null)
 s += arr[i].toString();
}
return s;
```